# Create contract using geth testnet

Tags: contract-development

I have tried this code and got this error below. How to solve this? And i'm using in geth testnet console.

```
var greeter = greeterContract.new(
    _greeting,
     {
       from: eth.accounts[0],
       data: '6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b6040516103a83803806103a8833981016040528080518201919050505b5b336000806101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1602179055505b806001908051906020019061008492919061008c565b505b50610131565b828054600181600116156101000203166002900490600052602060002090601f016020900481019282601f106100cd57805160ff19168380011785556100fb565b828001600101855582156100fb579182015b828111156100fa5782518255916020019190600101906100df565b5b509050610108919061010c565b5090565b61012e91905b8082111561012a576000816000905550600101610112565b5090565b90565b610268806101406000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff16806341c0e1b514610049578063cfae32171461005e575b600080fd5b341561005457600080fd5b61005c6100ed565b005b341561006957600080fd5b61007161017f565b6040518080602001828103825283818151815260200191508051906020019080838360005b838110156100b25780820151818401525b602081019050610096565b50505050905090810190601f1680156100df5780820380516001836020036101000a031916815260200191505b509250505060405180910390f35b6000809054906101000a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff163373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16141561017c576000809054906101000a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16ff5b5b565b610187610228565b60018054600181600116156101000203166002900480601f01602080910402602001604051908101604052809291908181526020018280546001816001161561010002031660029004801561021d5780601f106101f25761010080835404028352916020019161021d565b820191906000526020600020905b81548152906001019060200180831161020057829003601f168201915b505050505090505b90565b6020604051908101604052806000815250905600a165627a7a72305820789d3050c1c035a9173118a00cd27d493154ed1d6214251726788760d5d3ac6a0029',
       gas: 3000000
       }, function(e, contract){
       console.log(e, contract);
       if (typeof contract.address != 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
          }
       }) .
```

**Error text:**

```
 Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string without 0x prefix into Go struct field SendTxArgs.data of type hexutil.Bytes undefined
```

Answer (score 6):

Your data string has to start with 0x, rather than just the raw data. Try again but with 0x and then your data string, so it looks like:

data: '0x606060405234.....